# ActiveXObject error

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-browser, activex

I have to use an ActiveXObject into my site.
I have read that is only for IE but is there some way to escpae this problem?
Because I need to take an XML from a server and this company told me to use a code like this to retrieve data in XML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_XMLReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
g_XMLReq.open("POST", "LINK",false);
g_XMLReq.send(unsescape(XMLdata));
</script>
```

I think that is impossible to escape this problem? I have only to use IE?! And the user that navigate the site? Not all use IE only a little part.

Comment: Example: [Parsing complex XML with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11209139)

Comment: ok but the company that give me data told me to use this script.. I don't know if I make a request with anoter method I retrieve data @Pekka웃

Comment: If you must use `Microsoft.XMLTTP`, there is no way to do this without IE.

Comment: Great... I have to think to store all this information to a database with a cron and user take information not from xml directly but from database @Pekka웃

Comment: I'm not sure why, Alessandro. The requirement of using that exact method sounds pretty dumb, seeing as there are much better methods available. Do they know what they are doing?

Comment: I think that they know well... is one of the biggest provider that store data of most of American hotel @Pekka웃

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Non-ActiveX versions of XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) have been in browsers for many years. Even Internet Explorer has supported the native version since version 7. You appear to have been given some instructions that predate 2006.

Replace `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` with `new XMLHttpRequest()`. (Unless you need to support IE 5/6 in which case you'll have to try/catch it and the ActiveX version)